# How can I create a DateTime String using a date String and time String?

Tags: java, android, android-date

I want to create a DateTime String with format like `2013-08-30T15:06:00` using three strings.One String has Date `"30-aug-2013"` and second string has time `"15:06"` and last string has days value `"2"`.Now I want to use these three Strings to create a Resulted string like `"2013-08-28T15:06:00"`. The days value is to create date in past, so in this case the date changes from **30th aug** to **28 aug**

Solution I have tried:

```
public String getFormattedDate(String date, String selectedDays, String time) {
    String dtStart = date;  
    SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");  
    try {  
        Date dateObject = format.parse(dtStart);  
        System.out.println(date);  
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.setTime(dateObject);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.valueOf(selectedDays));
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime()); 
    } catch (ParseException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}
```

In above solution `calendar.add` will add the days instead of removing days from date.Also I don't know how to use the **time** string to set it on the date Object.

Comment: how do you go from 08-aug-2013 to 2013-08-30?

Comment: @njzk2 Sorry I didnt added that code, But SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd") will do the job

Comment: I mean regarding the actual date. what logic do you follow to replace 8th of august by 30th of august ?

Comment: @njzk2  Sorry I have edited the question, Thanks for pointing out this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your time `String` is always in that format, you'll need to use `time.split(":")` to get the hours and minutes.

You might want to specify the output format instead of using the `Locale` default format also.

Add a minus sign to substract instead of adding for the `Calendar.add()`.

Your code use `dd-MM-yyyy` but your month part is written, `08-aug-2013` which should be parsed using `dd-MMM-yyyy` instead.

This should output as you specified

```
  public static String getFormattedDate(String date, String selectedDays, String time) {
    String dtStart = date;
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.clear();
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"); // This should be MMM and not MM according to the date format 08-aug-2013
    try {
      Date dateObject = format.parse(dtStart);
      System.out.println(date);
      calendar.setTime(dateObject);
      String[] hoursMins = time.split(":");
      int hours = Integer.valueOf(hoursMins[0]);
      int minutes = Integer.valueOf(hoursMins[1]);
      calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
      calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
      calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // Here, I have no idea where you get the seconds, so I just set them to 0
      calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -Integer.valueOf(selectedDays)); // Add a minus sign to substract
      // System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
      // Use a SimpleDateFormat instead

      System.out.println(outputFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
      // System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return outputFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
  }
```

For a good place to read about formatting symbols, check [the bottom of this link](http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/), it's pretty well explained.

Calling `getFormattedDate("08-aug-2013", "2", "15:05");` with this code output `2013-08-06T15:05`.

Edit : I forgot the seconds, the output is now : `2013-08-06T15:05:00`

Answer (score 0):

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

String date = mYear + "-" + mMonth + "-" + mDay; // + time + ... so on
```

Comment: @I am sorry I didn't get your answer properly

Comment: Using '+' will add all the string variable .so, palce '+' as i put to add add year,month and day

Comment: Will you please read my question again and read the last line carefully

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar.add` can remove days by adding a negative value:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");  <-- check your format      
Date d = format.parse("08-aug-2013");

Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(d);
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -2);  <-- see that you are parsing to a negative int
System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

Prints:

> Tue Aug 06 00:00:00 EDT 2013

Comment: Thanks for answering how to remove days from date :)

Answer (score 0):

## Avoid j.u.Date & .Calendar

The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Instead use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

## Time Zone

The other answers ignore the critical issue of time zone. You must specify whether this string represents a date-time in Paris, Tukwila, or Kolkata. If you do not specify, the JVM's default time zone is applies.

## Language

The other answers fail to specify the language by which to parse the name-of-month.

## Example Using Joda-Time

```
String input = "30-aug-2013" + "15:06";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "d-MM-yyyyH:mm" );
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
java.util.Locale locale = java.util.Locale.ENGLISH;
DateTime dateTime = formatter.withLocale( locale ).withZone( timeZone ).parseDateTime( input" );
```

If required, convert to a java.util.Date, automatically adjusting to UTC as a Date has no time zone.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```